# Windows Can't connect to server

Tags: ip, internet-connection

I'm trying to connect to a private server at my college at address 172.17.16.55 and my Ethernet connects me at IP address 172.17.16.139.
This is the link I normally use http://172.17.16.55:51080/hub/login

Is this why I can't connect to the server? should my IP address match the server's IP address?

I tried to ping the service using cmd and this is the outcome:
[image: outcome]

This is the connection error I'm getting:
[image: connection error]

Comment: What does this mean? `why I can't connect to the server`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. We need more information to help you troubleshoot this problem. What service are you connecting to? Can others connect to it? Can you connect to other services on that server? Can you ping it? What else have you tried?

Comment: "my ethernet connects me at IP address 172.17.16.139". You need to be a lot more specific and accurate about your problem description, because this makes no sense at all. And no, your IP address _shouldn't_ match the servers IP address. The whole idea is that IP addresses are _unique_ in a network.

Comment: Ping says that the server is up, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the service on that server is running. What is the connection error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

With the information your provided, the following things are happening:

- The server is reachable, so your network configuration is correct
- The application at port 51080 is not responding. The specific error message (connection timeout) leads me to believe that either:

  - The application is hanging
  - A firewall was activated on the server

If the application was stopped and there was no firewall, the OS would respond with a reject instead of a timeout.

Either way, you need to contact the administrator of the server and have them check it out.